# Infragistics UltraToolbarsManager - adding ApplicationDefaults to QuickAccessToolbar

Tags: winforms, infragistics

Currently my QuckAccessToobar (QAT) shows only `Show Below the Ribbon` and `Minimize the Ribbon` options. I would like to add more options there, like in WordPad sample:

[image]

I found non infragistics related explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-controls-quickaccesstoolbar). It says about using `QuickAccessToolbar.ApplicationDefaults` property.

I found how to add tools to QAT itself (not dropdown) [here](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wintoolbarsmanager-add-a-tool-to-the-quick-access-toolbar). But there is no `ApplicationDefaults` property on `ultraToolbarsManager1.Ribbon.QuickAccessToolbar`

How can I add items to QAT dropdown so that users can check/uncheck them during runtime to display/hide buttons from QAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that ContextMenuTools property on UltraToolbarsManager.Ribbon.QuickAccessToolbar is exactly what I need.